# Fastest way to find number of digits of an integer?

Tags: go

I am trying to build a function which validates the given input. The input is an integer value. My question is, Which method should be the most effective and efficient

```golang
count := 0

for number != 0 {
  number /= 10
  count += 1
}

return count
```

or

```golang
len(strconv.Itoa(intValue))
```

Kind Regards

Comment: [Benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) each way & decide which one is best for your use case.

Comment: The loop has no memory allocations, and Itoa will do something similar. In this case I'd go with the loop.

Comment: Pedantic nitpick, but may help to think about problems like this - integers have no length. You're looking for the number of decimal digits. The distinction is relevant in some cases, just not this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a benchmark, with a fix for the loop method to return 1 for the input 0:

```
func lenLoop(i int) int {
    if i == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    count := 0
    for i != 0 {
        i /= 10
        count++
    }
    return count
}

func lenItoa(i int) int {
    return len(strconv.Itoa(i))
}


const num = 834589

func BenchmarkLoop(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        lenLoop(num)
    }
}

func BenchmarkItoa(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        lenItoa(num)
    }
}
```

[*Note that these only work on positive numbers*]

Output on my machine:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4771 CPU @ 3.50GHz
BenchmarkLoop
BenchmarkLoop-8     213208418            5.535 ns/op
BenchmarkItoa
BenchmarkItoa-8     33039769            33.74 ns/op
```

Note that you could get different results for a different size of an input number; I picked length 6 as typical, but you could try other options. For shorter numbers, the extra machinery in `Itoa` makes it even slower (in relative terms) than the loop. For huge numbers it's "only" 4x slower than the loop.

---

The `log10` method proposed in another answer is 2x slower than the loop (once fixed to handle corner cases correctly)

Comment: The log method would presumably be more performant with large `math/big` `Int`s.

Comment: @colm.anseo: for huge `int`s, the log method is 50% slower than the loop. For very large `bit.Int`s, they probably store their length? Like the `BitLen` method?

Comment: On modern architectures, multiplying a number is much faster than dividing a number; so it would be faster to comparing a (growing) 10's exponents to the number than dividing the given number itself. For code see my answer.

Comment: @leafbebop: that's a good observation. Thinking about it, I would guess that using LZCNT (or an arch-appropriate equivalent) plus a bit more bit fiddling would be even faster. Once you know when the first 1 bit appears, you can estimate the number's size in the range `(N,2N)` for some N. Extracting the number of digits from that can't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things happening here. If you are validating inputs, you probably ***shout NOT*** evaluate the input and **keep it in the string (or []byte) from**; which is to say, a simple calling `len(input)` would be most efficient, unless the inputs coming in some binary formats (or other formats that encodes integers directly instead of its representation), but even if that's the case, there is probably a way to narrow down the length in decimal using simple arithmetic methods (without using log or converting to float number).

If the given input is indeed an `int`, there are several way to handle it, and the goal is to do as less as possible, in which type conversion (unless it's between `int`s) are very wasteful.

With this in mind, the simple way of iterating to count the digits is good enough (and bonus point for being branch predictor friendly); however, on modern architectures, multiplying a number is much faster than dividing a number; so it would be faster to comparing a (growing) 10's exponents to the number than dividing the given number itself.

```
func lenLoop10(i int) int {
    if i >= 1e18 {
        return 19
    }
    x, count := 10, 1
    for x <= i {
        x *= 10
        count++
    }
    return count
}
```

*Note: multiply can overflow, so we need to check the bounds; on 64 bit architectures, `int`'s max value is bigger than 1e18 but smaller than 1e19, hence the initial check.*

Here's a benchmark testing on random workload within range of positive `int64`s.

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: st.ack/ilog10
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkLoop-8                 24724068                45.26 ns/op
BenchmarkItoa-8                 16520800                62.47 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop10-8               415604792                2.824 ns/op
BenchmarkLoopPrecalc-8          100000000               11.51 ns/op
BenchmarkSearch-8               62924082                18.11 ns/op
BenchmarkSearchManual-8         180194925                6.741 ns/op
PASS
ok      st.ack/ilog10   34.460s
```

Note 1: I do include a range over pre-calculated exponents of 10s, and it's slower than just multiplying it by the go.

Note 2: I also includes two versions of using binary search against the pre-calculated exponents of 10s: one using `sort.Search` and one hand written. `sort.Search` is good, but multiple function calls is too heavy here. The hand written version eliminates function calls and has a much better performance, but still slower than the simple `loopLen10`.

Note 3: While pre-calculating values can save time at runtime, accessing memories are actually not free, and can especially not considered free when doing this light operations. And branch predictor is not a force to ignore.

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Qpd0W8Gdad1